# Payload is [#document : null]

Tags: java, mule

We have a transformer in java code

```
public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding) throws TransformerException {
    try {
        Document document = DocumentHelper.stringToXml(message.getPayloadAsString(), true);
```

`message.getPayloadAsString()` used to return the xml document as a string that was passed in.
However when moving from Mule 3.2 -> 3.6 this code no longer works and we get

> [#document: null]

as the result of message.getPayloadAsString(). Has something changed in the mule versions, is there some sort of conversion needed now?

Comment: I noticed the payload of the message has changed from `org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage
{
  payload=org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl` to `org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage
{
 payload=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl`

Comment: try to use <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer /> right before this java transformer and ur code should work